# Powershell formatting issue - arm template -WhatIf [ANSI escape/color]

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm no powershell wizard but I'm having some interesting results with formatting having date time stamps in my result.  I have had this testing what-if for arm template as well as terraform in my pipeline, I haven't had any luck finding a fix for it.

Let's say I am running a what-if for a test arm template:

`Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult -TemplateFile ./test-arm.json -TemplateParameterFile ./test-arm.params.json -ResourceGroupName whatIfRg -ResultFormat FullResourcePayloads`

or simplified version

`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName whatIfRg -TemplateFile ./test-arm.json -TemplateParameterFile ./test-arm.params.json -WhatIf`

This runs fine, but my returned result looks like this:

```
Resource and property changes are indicated with this symbol:
  [38;5;77m+[0m Create

The deployment will update the following scope:

Scope: /subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg
[38;5;77m
  + Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DefaultNSG[0m [2019-11-01][38;5;77m

      apiVersion[0m:[38;5;77m "2019-11-01"
      id[0m:[38;5;77m         "/subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DefaultNSG"
      location[0m:[38;5;77m   "eastus"
      name[0m:[38;5;77m       "DefaultNSG"
      type[0m:[38;5;77m       "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"

  + Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/firstVnet[0m [2019-11-01][38;5;77m

      apiVersion[0m:[38;5;77m               "2019-11-01"
      id[0m:[38;5;77m                       "/subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/firstVnet"
      location[0m:[38;5;77m                 "eastus"
      name[0m:[38;5;77m                     "firstVnet"
      properties.addressSpace.addressPrefixes[0m:[38;5;77m [0m[[38;5;77m
        0[0m:[38;5;77m "192.168.10.0/24"
      [0m][38;5;77m
      properties.subnets[0m:[38;5;77m [0m[[38;5;77m
        0[0m:[38;5;77m

          name[0m:[38;5;77m                               "firstSubnet"
          properties.addressPrefix[0m:[38;5;77m           "192.168.10.0/25"
          properties.networkSecurityGroup.ID[0m:[38;5;77m 
"/subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DefaultNSG"

      [0m][38;5;77m
      type[0m:[38;5;77m                     "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
[0m
Resource changes: 2 to create.
```

I want the format to look normal like this:

```
Resource and property changes are indicated with this symbol:
  Create

The deployment will update the following scope:

Scope: /subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg
  + Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DefaultNSG

      apiVersion "2019-11-01"
      id         "/subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DefaultNSG"
      location   "eastus"
      name       "DefaultNSG"
      type       "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"

  + Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/firstVnet
      apiVersion              "2019-11-01"
      id                      "/subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/firstVnet"
      location                "eastus"
      name                    "firstVnet"
      properties.addressSpace.addressPrefixes
         "192.168.10.0/24"    
      properties.subnets      
          name                              "firstSubnet"
          properties.addressPrefix          "192.168.10.0/25"
          properties.networkSecurityGroup.ID 
"/subscriptions/[removed]/resourceGroups/whatIfRg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DefaultNSG"      
          type                 "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"

Resource changes: 2 to create.
```

I am having a hard time finding documentation to remove the date/time stamping in the results. If anyone knows a parameter to pass or if my PowerShell needs to be modified to not show the stamps it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more troubleshooting and pasting the text into notepad++ I was able to see ESC characters plus the numbers which I thought were date/time related.

The issue is ANSI escape color related and by default support is disabled in Windows 10.

The best solution for this issue is updating to PowerShell 7.2 where ANSI escapes/colors are supported. Any version below this doesn't work.